# Generate HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit: AWS Programmatic access

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

**Question.**
 I want to restrict some AWS CodeCommit user's AWS console access.
 If I give them "AWS Programmatic access", how can they generate Git
 the password to use AWS CodeCommit?
How can I achieve this by not giving them AWS console access?

Comment: I think you need to use [Credential Helper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html#setting-up-https-unixes-credential-helper)

Comment: @Marcin My idea is not to give users AWS console login. They have configured the ```git config --global https.proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
git config --global credential.helper "!aws codecommit credential-helper $@"
git config --global credental.UseHttpPath true
git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"
git config --global user.email username@xxxx.xx``` If I send them repository URL how can they enter the HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit when they clone repo?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Create an IAM User with access key ID and a secret access key (No need to provide these secrets to your users)
2. Attach 'AWSCodeCommitFullAccess' permission to this IAM User
3. Create Git Username and Password in AWS IAM Console. This is your secret sauce to access CodeCommit
4. Provide your users with Repo clone URL (HTTPS) and their Git username and password (created in Step-3)

These steps are presented here in elaborate details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html